# The Applications Menu Is Too Wide

Tags: applications

Running Loki and when I click on the Applications menu to reveal all available applications, it is far too wide for my laptop screen and many of the options are off screen. Does anyone know where the width setting for that is so I can reset to something more reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, rebooting fixed it. D'oh